# Understanding Tcl Polymorphism

Tags: polymorphism, tcl

In Tcl a variable and a procs can have the same name ...

for instance I can have

```
set container(alist) {}

proc container a {puts " do something"}
```

Um ... what other forms of polymorphism exist in tcl? ... I am looking at some code and I see stuff like this.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is really polymorphism.

A variable, be it a plain variable or an array can have the same name as a `proc`, but tcl knows which is which from the context.  Have a look at the **`info`** command. `info procs` and `info vars` in particular.

The two live in different name spaces within the interpreter (not to be confused with the TCL `namespace` command by the way)

Comment: Indeed, this is a more of a Lisp-1 vs. Lisp-2 type thing than polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism refers to one object being able to be seen as and used like a different type of object.  In your example, you have a variable and a proc with the same name but they are not, and indeed cannot, be treated as each other (the variable cannot be called like a proc and the proc cannot be treated like a variable).

You could also argue that there is no polymorphism possible in TCL.  Since TCL treats everything as a string (it's a typeless language), there is no "other" data type.  Thus, you can't treat an object of type A as if it were of type B because no type B exists.

You can create a sort of pseudo-polymorphism for procs by defining procs with the same name in different namespaces.  However, that is not as much polymorphism as it is operator overloading.

You may want to read [this article](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14742) regarding polymorphism on [The TCLers Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not polymorphism as such (the names are just looked up in different ways), but the three main areas of naming are *commands* (e.g., procedures), *variables*, and *namespaces*. There are a few other ones too (such as channels) but they usually don't have overlapping names anyway.

If you have 8.6, another major class of “polymorphism” is method names.